# How to get Okular to parse a pdf's table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, pdftex, okular

I am writing my thesis as a latex book which I compile using pdflatex. I use Okular to read pdfs, and I have seen that sometimes it displays the contents of a book in a clickable form. I would like to be able to do this for my thesis as well, but I can't find how to do it.

Comment: `\usepackage{hyperref}` should be used then ;-)

Comment: This was precisely it! Maybe you should submit it as an answer so that I can   send some imaginary points your way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package `hyperref` provides the support for hyperlinks and bookmarks (if called with the correct options)

Be sure to use `\usepackage{hyperref}` as one of the last packages to be loaded.

Exceptions: `cleveref` and `glossaries` should be loaded after `hyperref`.

Comment: (Some other exceptions; [Which packages should be loaded after hyperref instead of before?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1863))